# Using jQuery to parse a HTML structure

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I was hoping to get some help in getting a "price" field out of a radio button structure on a HTML page. It consists of between 1 and 4 radio buttons. Only 1 will be checked. Each radio button is in the following structure:

```
<span class="ajs-attr" id="v_5532_1_1"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_1" value="1" checked="checked"  onclick="ChoiceChanged(this, 'http://www.tgurney.co.uk/cgi-bin/dx000003.pl', 397)"> Fat Quarter &#58;  £2.75</span>
```

This one is checked. The only difference between each radio button is the `id=` field and the `value=` field.

I need to get is the price (as a number if possible) which is at the end of the structure. In this case "£2.75". I need it for the radio button that is checked.

I am really new to HTML and jQuery so I was really hoping someone could help me with the code.

So far I got the value back by using:

```
Perm = $('input[name=' + ButtonName+ ']:checked').val();
```

where `ButtonName = "v_5532_1"`.

I am struggling to get any of the text after that point. I may well be using the wrong jQuery code.

Comment: Sorry. Based on the very helpful answers below I should make clear i am using a 3rd party system that generates the radio buttons. I cannot change this part of the code to add in an identifier for the price. Sorry for any confusion. Thanks once again to everyone posting answers. Very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the input is self closing tag, you can get the value but not the text. The text belongs to the parent which is the `<span>`

**Use this to get the text:**

```
Perm = $('input[name=' + ButtonName+ ']:checked').parent().text();
```

To get number from the text(), use `Permtext.lastIndexOf('£')` to get the index of `'£'` then use `substring` to split the string and only keep the string after `£`. (note `lastIndexOf` will target the last `£` in string, so if you have `£` before it only take the last one)

the `+` before `Permtext...` will force the string to become type number.

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
  var Perm = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
  var Permtext = Perm.parent().text();
  var price = +Permtext.substring(Permtext.lastIndexOf('£') + 1);

  console.log('Perm text -->' + Perm.parent().text());
  console.log('Perm val  -->' + Perm.val());
  console.log('Perm number       -->' + price);
  console.log('type of Perm num  -->' + typeof(price));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ajs-attr" id="v_5532_1_1"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_1" value="1" > Fat Quarter &#58;  £2.75</span>
<span class="ajs-attr" id="v_5532_1_2"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_1" value="2" > Fat Quarter &#58;  £55.55</span>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thank you so much. That is great. I just need to strip out the number from this text field and I am sorted :). Thank you also for taking the time to write the code snippet.

Comment: @ag2 Cool =D Welcome to stackOverflow, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Comment: @ag2: I agree with Daniel... You accepted the answer too soon. But you can unaccept it. It will motivate him to improve... And if he doesn't, some other people will be more interested in posting their answer.

Comment: Will do. Thank you again. I know it is a bit cheeky but could I ask if you could add the code to extract the price as a number.

Comment: @ag2 you mean get the price from the text()?

Comment: @ag2 like `2.75` or `55.55`?

Comment: @ag2 check the updated one, hope it is what you need =D

Comment: Perfect. You are a star! Thank you so much :) Saved me days of trial and error!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that outputs the price as a flot number (decimal).
You'll be able to use it with the `price` variable.

```js
var price=0;

$(".ajs-attr input[type='radio']").on("change",function(){
  if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
    console.log( "TEXT: "+$(this).parent().text() );
    
    var textPrice = $(this).parent().text();
    price = parseFloat(textPrice.split("£")[1]);  // This value type is floating number (decimal)
    console.log( price );
  }
});

// I don't know what this function is...
// So just to avoid a script error, it is defined empty.
function ChoiceChanged(a,b){}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="ajs-attr" id="v_5532_1_1"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_1" value="1" checked="checked"  onclick="ChoiceChanged(this, 'http://www.tgurney.co.uk/cgi-bin/dx000003.pl', 397)"> Fat Quarter &#58;  £2.75</span>
<br>
<span class="ajs-attr" id="v_5532_1_2"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_1" value="1" checked="checked"  onclick="ChoiceChanged(this, 'http://www.tgurney.co.uk/cgi-bin/dx000003.pl', 397)"> Slim Quarter &#58;  £5.85</span>
```

Comment: Hi Louys. Thank you. I see that would make it much cleaner and simple. Unfortunately I am using a 3rd system and it would be quite problematic to amend this area of the code as it is generated by the system. Thanks again.

Comment: I see... You can't modify the HTML. In this case, the other answer is close. Ask him to output only the number as float type, not as a string... ;)

Comment: That would be perfect :))

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```js
$(function() {

  if (document.getElementById('v_5532_1').checked) {
    console.log($('input[name=v_5532_1]:checked').val());
  } else if (document.getElementById('v_5532_2').checked) {
    console.log($('input[name=v_5532_2]:checked').val());
  } else if (document.getElementById('v_5532_3').checked) {
    console.log($('input[name=v_5532_3]:checked').val());
  } else if (document.getElementById('v_5532_4').checked) {
    console.log($('input[name=v_5532_4]:checked').val());
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="price">
  <span class="ajs-attr"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_1" value="2.75" id="v_5532_1" > Fat Quarter &#58;  £2.75</span>

  <span class="ajs-attr"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_2" value="4.75" id="v_5532_2" > Fat Quarter &#58;  £4.75</span>

  <span class="ajs-attr"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_3" value="10.75" id="v_5532_3" checked> Fat Quarter &#58;  £10.75</span>

  <span class="ajs-attr"><input type="radio" name="v_5532_4" value="5.75" id="v_5532_4"> Fat Quarter &#58;  £5.75</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I see that would make it much cleaner and simple to use value=. Unfortunately I am using a 3rd party system and it would be quite problematic to amend this area of the code as it is generated by the system. Thanks again.